# Why is it that when I give an object to add to it's sprite group, it returns the objects/classes inside of it

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game and my current issue is that whenever I pass the Camera Object to add internally, It seems to return the Camera's
sprites. This is of course not good as I want to pass the Camera and not the Camera's Sprites. This works for everything else except this one class. Of course, I don't know if that's the case but I am certain that it is.

The main parts of the code that i'm having trouble with is the level function in GameState and the ElectricalSparks_Object class at the very bottom:

```
def create_level(self, TILE_SIZE, level, tile_dict):
    x = y = 0
    TS = (TILE_SIZE.x, TILE_SIZE.y)
    isbounds = False
    for i in range(len(level.level)):
        for n in range(len(level.level[i])):
            if level.level[i][n] == ".":
                if isbounds:
                    isbounds = False
                else:
                    isbounds = True
                break
            if not level.level[i][n] in tile_dict:
                x += TILE_SIZE.x  
                continue
            r = tile_dict[level.level[i][n]]
            cl = r["class"]
            InGameState = r["InGameState"]
            groups = r["groups"]
            if isbounds:
                l = []
                for E in groups:
                    l.append(E)
                l.append(inbounds)
                groups = l
            target = r["target"]
            cl(pos=(x, y),
                   size=(TS),
                   InGameState=InGameState,
                   groups=groups,
                   target=target)
            x += TILE_SIZE.x
        x = 0
        y += TILE_SIZE.y

class ElectricalSparks_Object(Entity):
def __init__(self,
             pos=(0,0),
             InGameState="static",
             groups=None,
             color=pg.Color("#0000FF"),
             size=(20,20),
             sprite=None,
             mass=400,
             target=None):
    super().__init__(pos=pos,
             groups=groups,
             color=color,
             size=size,
             sprite=sprite)
    self.sparks_timer = 0
  
def update(self):
    self.sparks_timer += dt
    if self.sparks_timer > 0.1:
        e = Particle(groups=(entities), size=(4,4), color=((40,59,190)), pos = (random.randint(self.rect.left,self.rect.right) - 5, self.rect.bottom - 5), vel = vec(rand(-2,2), rand(-2, -1)))
        e.gravity = 10
        self.sparks_timer = 0
```

I did some testing of my own to figure it out and found out that before creating the object, it showed the same thing like all the others (print), however, it changes after it is passed unlike the others.

I wasn't able to find anything like this on the internet that may lead me to a solution, so thank you in advance if you have anything that may help me find the answer.

Edit: So what I'm trying to do is pass the Camera object (The variable name is entities, and full class name CameraAwareLayeredUpdates) which is a child of pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates. The Camera calculates the scroll amount for every object in the game so it is necessary to pass every in-game object. My system is a tile based one using a txt file so I use a dictionary to contain the class and info such as in-game status. One of these is information on the groups (pg.sprite.Group) it will be going into. I use a tuple where I put all the groups, so when I pass it when creating the class, it will eventually reach the Entity class which is the basis of all of the other classes for in-game objects. Entity is a child of pg.sprite.Sprite and I believe that when passing the groups to super() it should add itself to the sprite groups in the tuple. To add to what I said about my own debugging, after I find what the tile indicates to I take the class and information from it. For EP (== ElectricalSparks_Object) the only group it has is the entities class (the variable name of the Camera Object). A print statement before I create the object, prints something similar to every other object. However when passed on creation it changes. I did this with the Entity class so I saw how the groups didn't change after creation except for this one class.

Comment: Where is there a `Camera` object here?  Remember, please, that if you are just printing the object, it will print whatever the ``_repr__` function returns.  If that function just shows you the sprites, then that's all you would see.

Comment: What is this code doing that you don't want?  You can't really expect us to wade through 2,000 lines of code to figure out what it's doing.  And many people won't click on an external link at all.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thank you for helping me in finding the answer indirectly. While trying to follow what you said to help others in helping me in finding an answer, I skimmed away the in bounds system showing the flaw in my system.  Either way, later in the future if I need help, I know better on what to put on my question and a new strategy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Put a comma after the first element in a tuple no matter what if you want that tuple to be a tuple only

```
tile_dict = {
            "S": {
                "class": SpawnPoint,
                "InGameState": "static",
                "groups": (collidables, entities, spawnpoints),
                "target": None
            },
            "P": {
                "class": Platform,
                "InGameState": "static",
                "groups": (collidables, entities),
                "target": None
            },
            "G": {
                "class": Grass,
                "InGameState": None,
                "groups": (collidables, entities),
                "target": None
            },
            "E": {
                "class": Enemy1,
                "InGameState": None,
                "groups": (enemies, entities),
                "target": p1
            },
            "B": {
                "class": Platform,
                "InGameState": "breakable",
                "groups": (collidables, entities),
                "target": None
            },
            "0": {
                "class": InBounds,
                "InGameState": "breakable",
                "groups": (entities),
                "target": None
            },
            "EP": {
                "class": ElectricalSparks_Object,
                "InGameState": "static",
                "groups": (entities),
                "target": None
            },
        }
```

While trying to skim down my code for easier reading and to lower the character count so I can put it up on this question, I found the solution/problem. With my system I have an in bounds system seen in the create_level function I had shown. A period represented the end  and start of the in bounds area, so when isbounds is true I take the groups and put them in a list and then append the inbounds group. The issue is, is that sometimes the groups wasn't in a tuple or list so it would instead give the sprites stored inside the object given which was the camera. I made my dictionary, however, to only have tuples for the groups information, but sometimes the tuple I have for groups contain only the entities variable (the Camera object). So basically it was an issue with python seeing a variable in a tuple by itself and turning it into only that variable or whatever is by itself. So to fix this I had to add a comma after the first element in a tuple no matter what, since if it contains only one thing it will turn into that. So i changed my dictionary like this.

```
tile_dict = {
            "S": {
                "class": SpawnPoint,
                "InGameState": "static",
                "groups": (collidables, entities, spawnpoints),
                "target": None
            },
            "P": {
                "class": Platform,
                "InGameState": "static",
                "groups": (collidables, entities),
                "target": None
            },
            "G": {
                "class": Grass,
                "InGameState": None,
                "groups": (collidables, entities),
                "target": None
            },
            "E": {
                "class": Enemy1,
                "InGameState": None,
                "groups": (enemies, entities),
                "target": p1
            },
            "B": {
                "class": Platform,
                "InGameState": "breakable",
                "groups": (collidables, entities),
                "target": None
            },
            "0": {
                "class": InBounds,
                "InGameState": "breakable",
                "groups": (entities,),
                "target": None
            },
            "EP": {
                "class": ElectricalSparks_Object,
                "InGameState": "static",
                "groups": (entities,),
                "target": None
            },
        }
```

Compare keys EP and 0 before and after.

Comment: If that works for you, then good enough, but REMEMBER that you can tell the difference by saying `if isinstance(xxx['E']['groups'], tuple):` and handling this at runtime.